# let user change activity color

Tags: android, background

I have an activity with four image buttons (red, blue, yellow, green)
the default background color for the activity is green
how to change activity color when button is clicked
e.g change background color from green to red when user click the red button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default set the color of your parent layout and initialize it in Activity as:

```
android:background="@color/green" or
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); onCreate of your activity

LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

Initialize 4 buttons in activity on their click write:

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

where layout is your main layout of xml file

set above color on particular buttons click events

Comment: In the xml file you have to add `android:` before `@color/green` `android:background="@android:color/green"`

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/green" android:id="@+id/mRlayoutSplash">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java File

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
RelativeLayout mainView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mRlayoutSplash);
// Set the color
mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.red);
```